# Simple mutation observer example in JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I try to add a `MutationObserver` in my web page to track changes in an image `src`, but that doesn't work.

Here's the code used:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("img").src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQsv7.jpg"
}, 2000);

var target = document.querySelector('#img');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });
});

var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: false,
  characterData: false
};

observer.observe(target, config);
observer.disconnect();
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7HT5.jpg" id="img" class="pic" height="100">
```

Comment: Which browser(s) did you try? Support is good but not ubiquitous - http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver

Comment: i try in google chrome

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you call `disconnect` method you will not receive notification anymore:

[Quote from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```
disconnect()
```

> Stops the MutationObserver instance from receiving notifications of
>   DOM mutations. Until the observe() method is used again, observer's
>   callback will not be invoked.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("img").src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQsv7.jpg"
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("img").src = "http://i.imgur.com/Xw6htaT.jpg"
    }, 4000);

var target = document.querySelector('#img');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });
});

var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
};

observer.observe(target, config);

// otherwise
observer.disconnect();
observer.observe(target, config);
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7HT5.jpg" id="img" class="pic" height="100">
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to have target at the time of Dom load to use this procedure ? Will it work if the target element is being appended by another method ?

Comment: @JithinB open a new question with the necessary details please, all the best