# Check for Dynamic Elements Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, mutable

Using jQuery, how can I detect dynamically-inserted elements? Something like this:

```
$('div#cart').on('mutate', function() {
    // Do something.
});
```

It needs to be able to trigger when elements that were not present when the DOM was originally loaded, even elements inserted using Ajax.

Comment: Assuming you have control over the dynamic elements, you can apply callback to those.

Comment: What you are looking for is a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). However be aware they are not well supported in older versions of IE. A better solution would be to fire a custom event yourself after updating the DOM

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can we suggest `DOMSubtreeModified`?

Comment: You just did :) although MutationEvents have been superceded by the MutationObserver

Comment: You need to trigger what? Maybe you don't need any mutation observer at all depending what is your use case

Comment: Checking for changes in the DOM doesn't really work very well, it's slow and clunky, and almost never needed, hence why they keep deprecating it and trying to come up with better solutions. If the elements are always inserted with jQuery, there most likely are workarounds, for instance just triggering something when the elements are inserted, or even hooking in to the internal `domManip` functionality in jQuery, which is used whenever something is inserted to the DOM with jQuery.

Comment: You can write event handlers for DOM elements that are not yet present in the DOM by enclosing them in a function. Once you add the elements to your DOM, you can call the function as & when required to bind the events.

Comment: arnabkaycee I'm not that good with jQuery, can you give me an example?

Comment: I ended up going with MutationObserver as found in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890937/simple-mutation-observer-example-in-javascript-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1):

There's an event called `DOMSubtreeModified`, which is something that observes the subtree for changes. I am not sure about its working in Internet Explorer or other browsers, but I am sure it works on the latest version of Chrome and Firefox.

Something like this:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#dom").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
    console.log("DOM content changed.");
  });
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("#dom").text("Hello, World!");
  }, 1000);
  $("button").click(function () {
    $("#dom").text("Button Change");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dom">Hello</div>
<button>Change Text</button>
```

Comment: Isn't `DOMSubtreeModified` deprecated?

Comment: @A.Wolff Yea kinda. I'll add a note. But it does work.

Comment: @A.Wolff Sorry, I didn't understand. What should I do? `:)` Also for some reason, it fires twice.

Comment: No my bad, i reedited previous comment. I meant you weren't filtering which kind of element is appended but OP doesn't ask for it, so...

Comment: @A.Wolff Ooh thanks... Yea, any idea why doesn't it fires twice?

Comment: I guess because how `$.fn.text()` internally works: `this.empty().append( ( this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document ).createTextNode( value ) );`  Calling empty() will fire it, then calling append() fires it again